Recording from different fields to the same table in ASP.NET MVC
I have a problem: when I press the add more button in ASP.NET MVC, it adds new fields on the .cshtml side, but I cannot save the data on the controller side.
My general purpose is that I want the fields opened when the add more button is pressed to be registered in the database as new data. So the more times the more button is pressed, the more data it should add, but it adds the data once.
public class EgitimSeminerViewModel
{
    public List<TBL_EgitimSeminerBilgi> EgitimSeminerBilgiList { get; set; }

    public EgitimSeminerViewModel()
    {
        EgitimSeminerBilgiList = new List<TBL_EgitimSeminerBilgi>();
    }
}

public partial class TBL_EgitimSeminerBilgi
{
    public int EgitimSeminerid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> GenelBilgiid { get; set; }
    public string EgitimKonu { get; set; }
    public string EgitimKurum { get; set; }
    public string EgitimSuresi { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> isDelete { get; set; }

    public virtual TBL_GenelBilgiler TBL_GenelBilgiler { get; set; }
}

